# ReferenceError: $tableRows is not defined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the above error and I can't seem to find the problem. I have tried various solutions posted here but I still can't get it to work.

I am relatively new to jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadCalc.init();

    var tableRows=$("#loadTable tbody tr");
    $tableRows.each(function(index){
        var $tableRow =jQuery(this);
    })

    $tableRow.find('.hours[]').on('change', function(){

        var hrs=$tableRow.find("[name=hours[]]").val();
        var qty=$tableRow.find("[name=quantity[]]").val();
        var watts=$tableRow.find("[name=acwatts[]]").val();
        var totalWatts=parseInt(hrs,10)*parseFloat(qty)*parseFloat(watts);

    })


    if (!isNaN(totalWatts)){

        $tableRow.find('.total[]').val(totalWatts.toFixed(2));
        var grandTotalWatts =0;
        $(".totalWatts").each(function(){

            var stVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
            grandTotalWatts += isNaN(stVal)? 0 : stVal;


            });
        $('#totalSystem').val(grandTotalWatts.toFixed(2));
    }

});
```

Comment: Typo.  `var tableRows` should be `var $tableRows`

Comment: @Taplar I still get $tableRow is not defined

Comment: Because of the scope issue I had previously mentioned, but that is a second issue.  If you ask multiple questions in a single question, then it becomes too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Naming variable by prefixing with $ isn't more recommanded with JQuery even if you could do it!

In your code, you have initialized the **tableRows** variables without prefixing it with $ but when you used it after you have added $ ($tableRows)!

So, you have two options:

1. Edit your `var tableRows = ....` to `var tableRows = ...` or
2. Replace your `$tableRows` to `tableRows`

Comment: @Denis glad it helped you :-)

Comment: @balzacLeGreek My idea was to autofill the totalwatts cell as the other cells are filled, but it doesnt seem to be working. Could you help me with that?